# Begin and end request in UpdatePanel using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, blockui, jquery-blockui

How get Method `BeginRequest` & `EndRequest` In `UpdatePanel`?(in jquery)

```
function onBeginRequest()
{
     //$.blockui;
} 

function onEndRequest()
{ 
     //$.unblockui;
}
```

Comment: related article i think : http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/

Answer (score 5):

```
with(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()  ) {
       add_beginRequest(onBeginRequest);
       add_endRequest(onEndRequest);
}

function onBeginRequest(sender, args) {
       $.blockUI();
}

function onEndRequest(sender, args) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can capture these events 
By Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() this.

Comment: That answer was already given almost two years ago, except with example code.. and without an external link. Do not include these links in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to have no problems with the update panel of your page!

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Put your code here
        });

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
           // Put your code here
        });

        prm.add_beginRequest(function () {
           // Put your code here
        });
```