# ASP.NET GridView inside UpdatePanel doesn't update until second click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I've looked for answers online but I have not found any answer. I have a GridView inside an UpdatePanel and one Linkbutton column to show some detail in a Bootstrap modal. I had a problem that when the user clicks on the LinkButton the event OnClick doesn't fire, so, to solve that I made a fuction in Javascript that only causes a click in another LinkButton to fire the OnClick event.

Now it works fine, but nothing changes until the second click.

ASP.NET code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upContent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grvOrderTracing" runat="server" EmptyDataText="There are no pending orders for the selected date" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDTSgetOrdersByDate" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" >
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Order ID" HeaderText="Order ID" SortExpression="Order ID" >
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="hide" />
                                <FooterStyle CssClass="hide" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="hide" />
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hide" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Number">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtShowMoreInfo" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showLog" CommandName="OrderID" Text='<%# Bind("[Order Number]") %>' style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold;" OnClientClick="ActivityLog(this);">
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtActivityLog" runat="server" CommandName="OrderID" CssClass="hide" OnClick="ActivityLog_Click" Text='<%# Bind("[Order ID]") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDTSgetOrdersByDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="sp_getOrdersByDate" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="filter" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="startDate" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="endDate" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLog" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="showLog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Orden Log</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:GridView ID="grvLog" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDTSgetTracing" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" GridLines="None" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Movement Date" HeaderText="Movement Date" SortExpression="Movement Date" ReadOnly="true" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="User" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="Action" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments"/>
                             </Columns>
                         </asp:GridView>
                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDTSgetTracing" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="sp_getTracing" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                             <SelectParameters>
                                 <asp:Parameter  DefaultValue="0" Name="ord_id" Type="Int32"/>
                             </SelectParameters>
                         </asp:SqlDataSource>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript code

```
function ActivityLog(lbt) {
    lbt.nextSibling.nextSibling.click(); //Find the other LinkButton and click
}
```

C# Code

```
protected void ActivityLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDTSgetTracing.SelectParameters["ord_id"].DefaultValue = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
    SqlDTSgetTracing.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    grvLog.DataBind();
    upLog.Update();
}
```

[When clicking the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTZNO.png)

[When clicnking the seccond time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPX9I.png)

After clicking twice now the data is displayed in the GridView.

I want that from the first click the data being displayed in the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to append `return false;` to the end of `OnClientClick` to prevent the rest of that control's click event (coded by ASP.NET for you) from running. That will ensure only the `LinkButton` you care about will postback.

```
OnClientClick="ActivityLog(this);return false;"
```

Not sure if that will fix the need for clicking twice or not, but maybe!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I appended return false; to the end of OnClientClick but still I have to click twice to update the gridview.

Comment: I bet it's a timing issue... when you click the first time the modal with the current HTML on the page shows (which doesn't contain your data), behind the scenes the postback may be occurring, but you don't "see" it until the second button press.  I would remove the `data-toggle` and `data-target` from the first LinkButton and use the `endRequest` function for the `UpdatePanel` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269912/begin-and-end-request-in-updatepanel-using-jquery). That function would then show the modal: `$('#showLog').modal();`. Hope that helps and gets you on the right path.

Comment: BTW - the method mentioned above will let you get rid of the double `LinkButton` solution and the first `LinkButton` can postback like you want... the set up and showing of the modal will be handled in the `endRequest` method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works pretty well! and also I just need a LinkButton instead of two. Thanks a lot!